# How to create item templates for SQL files, for Visual Studio Database Projects

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, stored-procedures, templates, database-project

It's possible to define your own custom templates for normal project types, such as templates for C# files, for a Class Library project.

What about a 'Database Project' scenario?

I would like to define a standard template for adding a stored procedure, which uses the company's conventions for all stored procedures, such as standard comments at the top.

---

After looking through an MSDN article on the topic, it seems as though the Database Project isn't supported:

> **Figure 5 TemplateData Elements for an Item**
>
> ProjectType |
> Indicates the type of project that this item can be added to. Possible values include CSharp, VisualBasic, VisualC, JSharp, and Web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see: [Create Reusable Project And Item Templates For Your Development Team](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188697.aspx)

VS Ref: [Visual Studio Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: This is a fine guide to creating templates for *supported* project types. However, it seems that the 'Database Project' type isn't supported. Refer to Figure 5: 'TemplateData Elements for an Item', under 'ProjectType'.

Comment: If I'm reading this forum post correctly, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsx/thread/d5ff6005-d5b2-4087-a725-a370981f614e, it can't be done.

Comment: Yup... guess I'm writing an email to Microsoft :)

Answer (score 1):

you can created customized project item templates for the database project , we do it all the time

the item must be placed in the following folder:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\Templates\Database Project Items

and then you can select it

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451032/how-to-edit-default-templates-for-database-objects-using-vsts-2008-database-editi] I think it covers what you are looking for as the path C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\Templates\Database Project Items doesn't appear to work in VS 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Extensions\SqlServer\Items

It's not the project template you're after, it's the item templates for each type of object.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result using code snippets. Once you have created your snippet (I copy/pasted one of the built-in SQL snippets), right click in your script file and select "Insert Snippet..."

The keyword replacement works nicely.